# Copy a Worksheet and Place it after all other worksheets and rename it as cell reference in another worksheet in the same workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to this site, I have a workbook, (Costing-Calculator) and in the workbook, I have many worksheets, but the sheets I am concerned with are named (Tour_Fare_&_Analysis) and (RoutePlanner).

What I want to do is Copy the Route Planner and place it after all other worksheets with values only (Without original formulas) and rename this new copy with value from Cell ("G2") in worksheet (Tour_Fare_&_Analysis).

In my searches I have found a code that did work initially, but later when I tried to change the code to make copy values only, i dont know what went wrong and even the original code is brining back error msg. The code I am using is as below and i have put the error ms too following the code.

```
Dim Test As Worksheet
Sheets("RoutePlanner").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
Set Test = ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Name = Sheets("Costing Summery").Range("G2").Value
```

Error Msg:
Run-Time error'1004':

Cannot rename a sheet to the same name as another sheet, a referenced object library or a workbook referenced by Visual Basic.

Please can anyone help me solve this issue, I will really appreciate any help as I have turned the google serches up-side down to try and find the answer to the error msg i am getting.

Comment: In an excel workbook, you can't have two worksheets with the same name. Check what is the value of `G2` It would be the same as one of the worksheets name.

Answer (score 0):

Been a while since the question, but here is how I solved a similar problem. I allow it to use the same name, but add a sequence number to the name.

(I also gotten into the habit of inserting stuff first or at the top, since I rearly need to look at the things I created a year ago, saves me the time of going to the end/bottom of everything.)

```
Sub OrderConfirmation()

Dim newsheet As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Dim OCNO As String

OCNO = "OC #" & ' adding the order number from a different sheet/row that Im working with

Worksheets("Template").Copy before:=Worksheets(1)
Set newsheet = ActiveSheet

On Error Resume Next
newsheet.Name = OCNO
    If Err.Number = "1004" Then
    For i = 1 To 10
    On Error Resume Next
    newsheet.Name = OCNO & "(" & i & ")"
    If Not Err.Number = "1004" Then i = 10

Next i
End If

End Sub
```